# how to get user timeline using twitterizer2

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using twitterizer2 to try and get a users recent few tweets and then write them to a table using oAuth not the users screen name, but i am new to twitterizer so i don't know how to do this.

```
        var step = Request.QueryString["p"].ToString();
        var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterKey"];
        var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterSecret"];

        if (step == "1")
        {
            var reqquest = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(key, secret, "http://localhost:2480/Site/Default2.aspx?p=2").Token;
            Response.Redirect(OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri(reqquest, true).AbsoluteUri);
        }

        else if (step == "2")
        {
            var token = Request.QueryString["oauth_token"];
            var verifier = Request.QueryString["oauth_verifier"];

            OAuthTokenResponse getTokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(key, secret, token, verifier);

            var oAuth_token = new OAuthTokens();
            oAuth_token.AccessToken = getTokens.Token;
            oAuth_token.ConsumerKey = key;
            oAuth_token.ConsumerSecret = secret;
            oAuth_token.AccessTokenSecret = getTokens.TokenSecret;

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(oAuth_token);

            foreach (var tweet in tweets.ResponseObject)
            {
                Response.Write(tweet.Text);
            }

            //TwitterStatus.Update(oAuth_token, "hello");
        }
```

how can i do this ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get the oAuth tokens of the user.

First of you'll need the user's accesstokens. You can retrieve these with

```
var requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "your return url").Token;
Response.Redirect(OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri(requestToken, true).AbsoluteUri);
```

This should ask you to sign in to Twitter. Than you'll return to the return url you've set, with oauth_token and oauth_verifier in the QueryString. These are the accesstokens.

Now you can use these tokens to retrieve the tweets of this user by using

```
 TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(authorization_tokens);
```

Iterate through these by doing something like this

```
 foreach (var tweet in tweets.ResponseObject)
 {
      string tweetText = tweet.Text;
 }
```

Comment: it seems to be working fine for posting but when trying to retrieve the time line using the code you provided i get this error: `Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Path '[1]', line 1, position 1864.`/

Comment: Twitterizer uses the Json.Net library to parse the Json that Twitter returns. There seems to be a problem that other users are also [experiencing](http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1096).

Do you have the latest version of Twitterizer2? Where did you get it? 

I've got mine from NuGet and haven't had this error.

Comment: thank you. i uninstalled and reinstalled via nuget and the error seems to be gone but now it throws this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` **at this line** `foreach (var tweet in tweets.ResponseObject)`

Comment: That means you haven't initialized `tweets` yet.

This line of code initializes `tweets`:

`TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(authorization_tokens);`

Comment: This means that ResponseObject is still null. There were no tweets that could be retrieved.
If you set a breakpoint, you can check what's exactly in the tweets object.

Comment: It was an error caused by json.net library so i downgraded to 4.0.5.0 and its working great now, thank you very much